# Export data from listview to OpenOffice VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a program that displays data from a CSV file into a ListView. 
I then have a button called "Reports" - when I click this I want the data to be displayed from the ListView/CSV file in OpenOffice Calc.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdReports_Click()
Dim oSM As Object
Dim oDesk As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim oSheet As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Instanciate OOo : this line is mandatory with VB for OOo API
Set oSM = CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManage…
'Create the first and most important service
Set oDesk = oSM.CreateInstance("com.sun.star.frame.D…
'Create a new doc
Set oDoc = oDesk.loadComponentFromURL("private:fact… "_blank", _
0, arg())
'Get the first sheet in the doc
Set oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)


With oSheet
For i = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count
.cells(i, 1) = ListView1.ListItems(i).Text
.cells(i, 2) = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(1)
.cells(i, 3) = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(2)
.cells(i, 4) = ListView1.ListItems(i).SubItems(3)
Next
End With
End Sub
```

At the moment all my button is doing giving me Run-time error '438' Object does not support this property or method
When I debug this line is highlighted:

```
.cells(i, 1) = ListView1.ListItems(i).Text
```

This code was written for Excel but I edited it so it can be displayed in OpenOffice Calc. 
Can anyone help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says - the statement is using a property of method that isn't supported by the Ole Automation interface. First question: can you use a type library (see the References dialogue - is there something like OpenOffice Calc in the list)? Knowing what methods and properties are available at compile time is much better - you can do the same with Microsoft Excel. Then you could declare your variables as a specific type, rather than "As Object".

Not knowing OpenOffice, I looked for documentation on OpenOffice, and found the next best thing, Star Office. Try: http://www.openoffice.org/api/basic/man/tutorial/tutorial.pdf  . Look at page 64, section 4.4 for documentation on the spreadsheets. The object model looks different to Office, which would explain your problem.

It looks as if you need to use the Sheet.getCellByPosition() method, rather than the Cells() method, e.g.

```
GetCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition (nColumn , nRow)
```